# $.each throwing error : Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '37' in

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON Object like below :

```
var data = "{'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}";
```

As it is in JSON format, no parsing required, so I just want to iterate the object using $.each as below:

```js
 $.each(data, function(index, value) {
   alert(index + ": " + value);
 });
```

It is throwing a console error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '37' in {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}(…)
```

I don't have any idea of what's going wrong. What is it?

Comment: data is a string and event not a valid JSON

Comment: @Pranav Can you elaborate?

Comment: $.each can apply for an object or an array... but you are using a string withit, either create an object or valid json and parse

Comment: *"As it is in JSON format, no parsing required"* That is exactly wrong. JSON has to be parsed into a native JavaScript value. Right now you have a string (that doesn't even contain JSON). You cannot use `$.each` on a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the way value assigned to data variable to something like below:

```
var data = {key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2'};
```

in place of

```
var data = "{'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}";
```

Comment: Explaining the difference would probably be helpful.

Comment: Previously data were assigned in string format. so need to remove **"** from start and end to make it object. and key does not have any type so no need to wrap key with **'**. Thus after making these changes it will be a proper object having multiple key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid json. so that it throws error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = {};
  data.key1 = "value1";
  data.key2 = "value2";

  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      alert(index + ": " + value);
      });
 });
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/0d7st5q7/

Comment: data = "{'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}" is it wrong?

Comment: the data variable has to be set with data attribute from dom element

Comment: yup, because it treated as string, and if you try to converted json object you may get error because of ascii characters. you can use this way also to declare object.  `code`  var data = {key1:"value1",key2:"value2"};

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, value) {
   alert(index + ": " + value);
 });
```